# MFC: wide char-based CMap makes program crash

Tags: c++, dictionary, mfc

got a question about a terribly simple but apparently unbelievably complicated thing - custom data CMap from MFC.

```
typedef CMap<PWCHAR,PWCHAR,PWCHAR,PWCHAR> TMyMap;
TMyMap m;
// the following causes a crash once "m" gets out of scope
m[L"xxx"]=L"yyy";
// the following causes a crash immediately (which is probably reasonable)
m[NULL]=NULL;
```

Using VS2010Express in combination with legacy MFC6 (i.e., this leathal combination doesn't allow me to trace the MFC source code, hence my apologizes for the probably very unnecessary question at first glance).

Many thanks for a reply.

Tomas

Comment: Could it be that `CMap<>` is trying to `delete` its keys (or values, or both) upon destruction?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it shouldn't even be aware that it is pointers that it is holding, so doubtful it's trying to delete. It's possible that MFC6 is making assumptions about the run-time library that don't hold in 2010.

Comment: Hi there, I think Mark is closer - deletion doesn't occur (I somehow was NOW able to trace MFC's source... - don't ask me how I did it as I've no idea!). Anyway, managed to track down the problem to the moment the hash table is created in CMap::InitHashTable. The following two lines don't like each other even if in immediate succession: (1a) `m_pHashTable = new CAssoc* [nHashSize]` and (2) `delete[] m_pHashTable`. If (1a) rewritten as (1b) `m_pHashTable = (CAssoc **)malloc(nHashSize*sizeof(PVOID))`, it works! :-) So the new question is, what's wrong with (1a)?

Comment: Are you using MFC as a DLL?  If so, was it built with its own copy of the runtime library?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MFC in a shared library (present in System32 folder) - that's because I can't compile it as a static library (a somehow implied restricton of using MFC6 under VS Express). But should it matter? Btw, I found out why I could track the code in this case - because it's a template, so something that the compiler knows about at the compilation time - I still can't track the prefabricated code. The malloc+delete commands are part of the template.

Answer (score 1):

So you compile the Code with VC-Express 2010 and linked to the MFC Libs from VC6 and this all with MFC in a shared DLL.

It may be that your EXE code is linked to the CRT runtime of VC 2010. Where the DLL code of the VC6 MFC will use the VC6 runtime CRT DLL.

So new/malloc/delete/free executed in the MFC code and your code will always target different heaps and this must crash.

Just check with Depends what CRT DLL is loaded by your program and what CRT is used by VC6.

Just step into the assembler code and debug it, to see what modules are involved.

Comment: Hi, so your suspicion of unintentionally mixing two different libraries prooved to be right! (Although I used for that "Dependency Walker", http://dependencywalker.com ). The app uses MFC42D.DLL, MSVCRT100D.DLL, MSVCRT.DLL, and MSVCRTD.DLL. Can I influence the usage of these libs somehow? Didn't find any of them in the project's properties - may it be something hardcoded for each version of VS?

Comment: The MFC DLL surely uses the VC6 dlls. And if you link ´with the current libraries of the VC-Express you code links to the CRT of the VC 2010.

I suppose it will work when you use static linking...
But I would never mix such libraries. The compiler might create completely other codes about exceptions and stack unwinding...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - will mark your response as answering the question as there is no other rational reason why it makes the troubles it does. Btw, I unfortunately can't link statically with the MFC library as this is, for some reason, impossible (see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/MFCinVisualStudioExpress.aspx - I at least managed to make MFC run in debug mode but that's it I'm affraid). Thanks again!

Comment: I read this article, but the only way would be static linking. But even than I wouldn't trust this way! Look at my other answer!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mixing the VC-Express with the old MFC VC6 stuff it would be easier to use the new Vs 2015 Community Edition. It is free for small companies (check the end user license) and will you allow to use the MFC.

May be this is a more stable way to get around such "mixing" problems.